# How do I repair damage to wood on cabinet from glue?

Tags: repair, wood, cabinets

I unfortunately stuck a door stop holder onto my cabinet and when I removed it. It took some of the wood with it.
Is there a way to repair this?

[image: door stop showing veneer stuck to it]

[image: cabinet door showing veneer removed]

Comment: How about a picture of the damage and the door stop.

Comment: Probably not real wood, more like a very thin, stick on cover.  Replacement of covering might be only option.

Comment: Put it back where it was?

Comment: you peeled off paper, not wood

Answer (score 1):

It is a paper simulated. I had to replace cabinets in one house,  but when I was a navy wife, I would go to hardware store in the stain section they have oil stain marking pens and you can match the color.

Comment: Yes, stain pens _might_ work, but it's probably nothing but particle board underneath, and those don't stain all that well. Another option is "regular" markers. My wife's got tons (not that she's an artist, she's a teacher), and will find 3 or 4 shades of brown/black to fill it in and match the pattern to her desired level of "good enough".